# Paragraph.Search throws GeneralException when Find window is open

Tags: office-js

When attempting to run a Paragraph.search an exception is raised if the Find, Replace, or Goto window is open.

GeneralException: GeneralException
   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:202747)
   at yi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:235283)
   at st (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:235370)
   at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:235190)
   at c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:233776)

```
ranges = paragraph.search(text, { matchCase: !caseInsensitive, ignoreSpace: true});
```

Any ideas?  If this is not workable it'd be nice to at least get a better exception so we can tell a user how to fix it (close the modal in order to navigate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. Great question and Yes, this is by design, sorry! The reason why this happens is because the search parameters (i.e. the settings you are using for case insensitive, ignore spaces among others) are single global and we don't want the API to interfere with the end user search experience.
At the same time having he user search both using an add-in and the built-in search seemed edgy.
That said I will work with the team to see if we can add a specific exception for this to give you more control. The ETA for this is undefined though.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree that two searches is a bit edgy, however i'm using search as a way to build out custom ranges as we do not have a lot of great options for creating ranges from sub sections of paragraphs.  It's not truly a search for me.  More of a work around from the current limitations for building ranges.

Comment: ok i understand, i would love to know the limitations you have. can you share more details on what limitations you are experiencing? have you seen the ranges  functionalities we have added to 1.3?

Comment: Sure,  in my example I found a particular string in a paragraph that i want to call out to a user.  Lets say its an address with a zipcode that doesn't match the city associated with it.  I need to build a range for this address string and the only real way to do that is with the search function.  It'd be really nice to be able to create arbitrary ranges like we can with the interop.  I'd love a range constructor that took an index and a length, or something similar.  There are a lot of use cases that require much finer grained control over range construction than what the current API provides